# Can I make a paper as OA after final files submission?

Tags: publications, ieee

Yesterday I submitted a paper to an IEEE hybrid Journal without choosing the OA policy. However, I found that my institution has an agreement with IEEE and it is possible to publish the paper as OA without paying.

Is it possible to change this before the final version of the paper is published?

Comment: Why not ask IEEE, and why not ask now rather than waiting all the way until the final version?

Comment: I've just written to the Editorial Office...

Comment: I assume OA is "Open Access".

Comment: Yes, Open Access

Answer (score 1):

Different publishers may handle this differently, but in m experience it's enough to just reply to whomever sent you the publication agreement and ask them to publish your article as OA. It's a good idea to remind them that your institution has a relevant agreement with the publisher. An agreement is an agreement. The rest should be a technicality.